how to fetch image or video files from user's smartphone as fast as tiktok or instagram
I'm making function that fetch image or video files from user's smartphone. At that time, I was using react-native-fs. but it is too slow to fetch files(In my case, it takes 3~5second, too slow, I think user will leave the app). When I used Instagram or tiktok, it fetched files from my phone in an instant. how to do that?

Are you sure? Or are they just pretending and then telling you its ‘processing’?

I don't know what its 'processing' means. Could you please explain in more detail?

@somethinghere
In an conclusion, I'm not sure. It's just guess.
I'm sorry for being confused of me.
but it really look like so.

@somethinghere After I delete data and enter the app and admit permission, image and video appear in an instant
